# Multisite Primary Domain Broken All Subsites Work

Tags: multisite, redirect

I am all out of tricks.

The primary domain of my multisite returns  "ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS", meanwhile my two subsites, on subsite.example.org function perfectly.

This started after a recent plugin installation (don't know which plugin, ithemes or litespeed), the site is old, everything was working well for months after the last migration.. I am pretty good about removing old plugins and tables from the db. The db is clean as I can get it.

I use wp-cli to migrate dbs, previously used `wp-migrate-db`...

**Troubleshooting that has not worked:**

1. Disabled all plugins
2. verified domain via phpmyadmin in `wp_options` (options table, blog table)
3. Restored original Multi site `.htaccess` provided within wp gui
4. Tried different `.htaccess` found in this forum (current):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

5. cleared cookies,  changed browser, used incognito
6. updated permalinks by changing from `post-name` to `plain` saving, then changing back again and saving
7. tried editing `wp-config.php` in various ways:

I currently have this in `wp-config.php`  (I include the  hashes `//` to show variations that I have tried)

```
/* Multisite */
//define( 'NOBLOGREDIRECT', 'https://example.test' );
define( 'NOBLOGREDIRECT', 'example.test' );

define( 'WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true );
define('MULTISITE', true);
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', true);
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'example.test');
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/');
define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
//define('WP_HOME','https://example.test');
define('WP_HOME','example.test');

define('WP_SITEURL','https://example.test');
//define('WP_SITEURL','example.test');
```

FF network console shows only correct request to the correct address:
[image]

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: where is it redirecting from and to? Use the network panel in the browser dev tools to figure this out with the option not to clear out entries on new requests turned on so you can see the HTTP redirects. Also when did this start happening and what lead to the situation you're in currently? If this is a new site, or if it's a migration that failed, etc, make sure that info is in your question, including details on how you did it and the tools that you used to do it

Comment: `Use the network panel in the browser dev tools to figure this out with the option not to clear out entries on new requests turned on so you can see the HTTP redirects. `  Can't figure this out... yet... will add more detail to the post..

Comment: @TomJNowell FF console -network and Apache Access both confirm only 301  requests to the correct address :-/

Comment: 301 requests to which address specifically and from what location? Be very specific and avoid implied facts to avoid confusion. State things outright and include hard information to avoid ambiguity. your last comment implies that when visiting the correct URL it will attempt to redirect to the exact same URL ( _exact_ not equivalent, same capitalisation, same URL parameters, same TLD, same HTTP/S protocol etc )

Comment: added screenshot, in case I misinterpret..

Comment: No idea was caused this problem.. but I just restored a 2 week old db and I will test plugins 1 by 1 to catch the culprit... got my site back